# TexShop doesn't compile any new documents after upgrading to Ventura 13.1

Tags: compiling, console

After I upgraded my Macbook to Ventura 13.1 (previously it was running on Catalina, I don't know which version though), I can't compile any new documents. It doesn't even open the console window after pressing "Typeset".

I can alternate and typeset old documents without any troubles. (I am using Texshop and writing in Latex, compiling a pdf).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I think there was one time where I upgraded the MacOS and had to reinstall MacTeX.  But, did not have that issue updating to the latest MacOS. However, since you say it compiles old documents, a reinstall proabaly won't fix the issue. I am just guessing here, but is there perhaps some permission issues? Does compilging a new document in the same directory as the old document work? What happens if you make a copy of an old document and compile the copy?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did copy an old document into a new document and it did not compile. I press the "typeset" button and nothing happens. I also noticed that if I try to close the window after I pressed "Typeset", I can't unless I quit texshop.  If I close the new window before pressing typeset, it closes fine.  I don't know what you mean by directory - I am somewhat of a computerdummy.

Comment: I have also. noticed, that quite often when I compile one of my old documents where I have added some more (new) content, and there is a compiling  error, I need to delete all the other files (apart from the .tex file of course) in order to make it work, after I corrected the error in the .tex file, which is rather annoying and time consuming....

Comment: By directory I meant the folder where the document is located. The need to delete the temporary `.aux` files is occurs if they get corrupted due to the compile failing. You can just use `File/Trash Aux Files' or the similar button in the console that appears when you typeset. Sorry, don't know how to help you further. I guess it can't hurt to reinstall MacTeX completely, but to me the issue here seems like some permissions related issue.

Comment: Hi, I am having the exact same issue as you @AnnickBiver. Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had (almost) the same problem.  But then I noticed that "Update Apple ID Settings" was required. I did, and the problem disappeared.

Comment: There was no question, but help was solicited.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I am experiencing the same issue as Annick.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, I had to update TexShop as well, now it's working fine again! Thanks for everybodys help!

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I installed TeXLive/2023 beside TeXLive/2022 and it seemed to modify (upgrade?)
TeXShop (as I guessed from the dates of the files).
But I experienced the same problem mentioned on this forum: TeXShop.app did not work.

I tried to remedy to that with "brew upgrade TeXShop".
THe process took a very long time, thereby showing some errors (access denied to remove
several aliases to fonts), and failed in the end.
Some messages said that TeXLive was missing some files, apparently contained in
Library/tex/texlive/2016 (or similar), but I checked that I have nowhere in my hierarchy
"texlive/2016".

I finally succeeded to get no errors from the installation of "texlive/2023"
by going to the TeXLive page and clicking on the "upgrade" button.
That downloaded MacTeX.pkg, and clicking on it upgraded/modified? texlive/2023.
I left texlive/2022 in its previous state as advised in the TeXLive pages.

Then TeXShop opened, but even from the Terminal I could not induce it to open any .tex file.

Today I tried first "brew upgrade TeXShop". It was refused ("no cask for texshop").

Then I did a "brew install TeXShop". Everything went smooth, and success was announced.

TeXShop.app had been left in the same state as last night...

But this time it works !

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.